# Does Appium and Calabash needs rooting or jailbreaking for automating tests on a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, jailbreak, appium, calabash

I am new to mobile automation space. My customer has a requirement that the Mobile automation solution should not be dependent on rooting(android) or jailbreaking(ios) devices.

I am currently looking at Appium and Calabash. I am not sure whether these 2 tools fit the above requirement.

Also please let me know if there are any other tool which will fit in my requirement (Except Monkey talk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appium and Calabash do not require rooting the device.

I prefer and work with Appium because you do not need to modify the target app's source code in any way. All other cross-platform automation solutions out there require you to modify the target app.

[Here's a list of some other automation solutions](http://dary.de/2012/03/open-source-mobile-test-automation-frameworks/)

Answer (score 2):

No. Rooted devices are not required to run tests on Appium and Calabash.  However, Appium and Calabash can also work on Rooted device.   As such, I think Calabash suits your requirement, so you can go ahead with that.

Answer (score 0):

I can personally speak on Calabash. It is a powerful tool as long as your proficient with setting up both iOS and Android environments. iOS requires duplicating and modifying the target and if you're using cocoa pods there is an additional mod that needs to happen [Cocoa pods update](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/25-Acceptance-testing-with-Calabash-and-CocoaPods)

Works great on devices and sims and has a powerful querying tool through the irb shell. The language to query vs the syntax in writing tests and ruby scripts are different. Other then that its great.